# Navigate to ViewController and dissmiss VC

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Here i'm dismissing one VC and trying to navigate new VC , but navigation not working. Dismiss VC working fine.

```
@IBAction func onClickEmailBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //dismiss VC
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    //Navigate to VC
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let cevc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CEVC") as! EmailViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cevc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here I have one NavigationViewController called VC1, on that I'm presenting one VC called VC2. In this VC2 when I click button I want to navigate new VC called EmailVC.

Comment: can you please share the hierarchy as well, is current controller is presented ?

Comment: Find out Root navigation controller and try to push with that controller.

Comment: @SGDev, I have one VC called VC1,  I'm presenting one more VC called VC2, when I click btn in that VC2 I want to navigate new VC3. Here I'm presenting VC2 with ` let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC") as! SecondViewController
               //present modal
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)`

Comment: Try to add pushViewController code in completion handler of  self.dismiss, without main queue

Comment: @ manishsharma93, can you please write code for me...

Comment: @SGDev You can't push view controller from navigationController of dismissing view controller

Comment: @manishsharma93 this will not work

Comment: @ manishsharma93 , self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let cevc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CEVC") as! EmailViewController
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cevc, animated: true)
            }
        }). it's not working

Comment: You have to pushViewController on navigation Controller who has presented your ViewController

Comment: @ Vikky, is there any solution for that

Comment: u don't need to use dispatch just add your redirection code in dismiss completion block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
@IBAction func onClickEmailBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CEVC") as! EmailViewController {
         self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
         self.presentingViewController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's getting errors **Pattern matching in a condition requires the 'case' keyword insert case** and what is controller here

Comment: after dismissing the self, self does not exist in hierarchy but the self.presentingViewController is exist. by using presentingViewController i can push my EmailViewController.

Comment: @SGDev  you can present a view controller from dismissing view controller, but can't push as you are doing it. OP's question was to push a viewController from dismissing viewController

Comment: you can push as well using presentingViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to push a ViewVontroller from dismissing view controller,
and the answer which you have accepted is presenting a viewController from dismissing viewController. Although it may serve your purpose, but I am going to answer you original question

```
   // get the object of presenting nanvigation controller(navigation controller with has presented this view controller)
    let presentingNavigationController = presentingViewController?.navigationController
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        let cevc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CEVC") as! EmailViewController
        // here you push your view controller with presentingNavigationController
        presentingNavigationController?.pushViewController(cevc, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out Navigation controller using below code and replace **Viewcontroller** with your Controller name.

```
let productVC = SeconViewViewController()
let parentVC = (parent!.presentingViewController as! ViewController).childViewControllers.first as! UINavigationController
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
     parentVC.pushViewController(productVC, animated: true)
})
```